# How to set a Finder-window background image on a disk image volume

Tags: cocoa

Generally to distribute a simple cocoa application we make dmg of its release folder. When we double click on it, it mounts its image and displays an un-editable window with .app and/or other files, such dSYM, contained within it. Right now the un-editable window appears with white background and icons of files within it.

**My requirement is**:

> To customize un-editable window such
>   that I can display some images in
>   background, change location and size
>   of icons and customize other
>   appearance features within it. eg. Skype, Growl install windows.

Can anyone suggest how can I implement it?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cheapest way would be to create the disk image normally, mount it, tell the Finder to open its window, and tell the Finder to set the window's background picture. Here's [the source code for the Growl project's script for this](http://code.google.com/p/growl/source/browse/Release/dmg_growl.applescript?spec=svn7de3aa4ef83ee1f8bf28eb2796eef6c9a8a4d089&r=7de3aa4ef83ee1f8bf28eb2796eef6c9a8a4d089).

The downside to this solution is that you pretty much can't use your Mac while the script runs, lest you throw the script off track.

Comment: ok..... thanx for both of your answers... I have also explored an easy trick for it, check my answer!

Comment: Hi @PeterHosey, Google has apparently changed the way files are referred to in code.google.com so anyone clicking on your above link will get a 404. I was able to find [your latest checkin here](http://code.google.com/p/growl/source/browse/Release/dmg_growl.applescript?spec=svn7de3aa4ef83ee1f8bf28eb2796eef6c9a8a4d089&r=7de3aa4ef83ee1f8bf28eb2796eef6c9a8a4d089), but it'd probably be smart to come up with an even better (and more persistent) link for this useful applescript.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be [DropDMG](http://c-command.com/dropdmg/).

Answer (score 0):

An easy trick is:

> Create a read/write enabled dmg, set
>   it up like you want it to look, load
>   the app and then convert it to a
>   compressed read only dmg.

cheers... :)

Comment: That's basically what I said. You just left out the part about scripting it, so you're proposing doing it manually every time.

Comment: yeah... you are right ...my solution will not work if I transfer the dmg created with background image to other mac... you really offered a better solution!